# How to pass a formatted string as a single argument in C?

Tags: c

How would I go about formatting a string and passing it as a single argument in C? If I wanted to use `sprintf()`, I would have to create a variable first and then store the formatted result in there before passing the variable. This feels messy. Is there any way around this? Or is that how it should be done?

Comment: In C++ 20, you can use `std::format` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). However, in C, I think there's no such function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "passing it as a single argument".  Some Linux and FreeBSD systems provide `asprintf`, which allocates the memory for you (but then it is up to you to free it later).

Comment: @NateEldredge If I have some function that takes in a single argument `char *msg` and I wanted to call it with a formatted string like `myFunction("My message: %s", mymsg);` then that'd count as two arguments.

Comment: I see.  Then no, there isn't any way around creating a new string.

Comment: You had better get used to C being a bit tedious. There are reasons for that. Memory management is one of the most important ones of those reasons.

Comment: While C doesn't give you many automations, it's not messy at all. You should think of C as essential and as an opportunity to know how some stuff works at a deeper level

Answer (score 2):

The "*messy*" part can be isolated into a helper `myFmtFunction` function, which builds the string then calls the real `myFunction`. The formatting helper could actually be reused for different `myFunction` targets, by passing an additional function pointer argument (though the sample code below does not do that, in order to keep it simpler).

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myFunction(const char *msg)
{ printf("[myFunction] %s: %d\n", msg, rand() % 6 + 1); }

void myFmtFunction(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  // determine required buffer size 
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  if(len < 0) return;

  // format message
  char msg[len + 1]; // or use heap allocation if implementation doesn't support VLAs
  va_start(args, fmt);
  vsnprintf(msg, len + 1, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  // call myFunction
  myFunction(msg);
}

int main() {
  const char s[] = "dice roll";
  const int n = 3;
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    myFmtFunction("%s %d of %d", s, i, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Possible [output](https://godbolt.org/z/rWfo1r):

```
[myFunction] dice roll 1 of 3: 2
[myFunction] dice roll 2 of 3: 5
[myFunction] dice roll 3 of 3: 4
```